# How to do submenu in Ext.js ComboBox

Tags: extjs, combobox

Ext.js SplitButton has menu with submenu built into it, how can I do the same thing with Combobox? especially with static data?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Ext.define('MenuTrigger', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    createPicker: function() {
        return new Ext.menu.Menu({
            items: [{
                text: 'Foo'
            }]
        });
    }
})

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new MenuTrigger({
        renderTo: document.body
    });

});
```